# Wicket - Redirect with RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException

Tags: java, wicket

Again I return with a wicket problem.

A common way to implements redirection between pages in wicket, is througt RestartResponse...Excepion.

My application doesn't have a login page and login is made by singleSignOn another portal.
My Login page has 2 constructor:

```
//bad login if used a direct url to login page that is bookmarkable
public LoginPage() {
   super("Login");
   throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(new EmptyPage("Login on SMURFS PORTAL is necessary"));
}
    //good login from portal
public LoginPage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super("Login");
       ...
}
```

EMpty Page is a very simple page with a LABEL with wicket:id = "message".

```
public EmptyPage(String message) {
   super("Alert");
   add(new Label("message", message));
}
```

Wicket redirect correctly to empty page but the code of empty page is not printed even if the title of the page is "Alert". The section where the "child" element should be attach, is empty like EmptyPage was without any markup.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: what is actually in EmptyPage, since the code above doesn't extend Page I presume its an example rather than something you have run.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that `this.message` refers to a field that hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Sorry. Problem during cut and paste. Consider message instead of this.message.
I have corrected the code above.